# How do I get the type of the value of a node in an XML document

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml document that was generated using the WriteXml() method of a DataSet. I also used the XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema option. I've opened up the resulting file and found that the resulting schema information provides a list of childnodes and the subsequent types of the values associated with them. For example:

```
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="studentID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="studentRank" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="studentLastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="studentFirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="homePlanet" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="studentStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
   <xs:element name="TestColumn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
```

I'm searching for a simple way to access the "type" attribute (and it's subsequent value). For example, I'd like to be able to display something like:

"studentID is of type int", 
"studentRank is of type string"

So far all my Google searches on how to get the type of the value of a node have turned up code samples that seem much more complicated than what I'm trying to achieve here. Any suggestions (especially on tutorials that demonstrate how to do this) would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this which means the actual value would go inside the tag for the data type.  Or if the data type for each field is not changeable then you could add your own attribute for each of those elements that indicates the data type.

```
Variable data type for an element:
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="studentID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="unsignedInteger" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="signedInteger" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="float" type="xs:float"/>
            <xs:element name="string" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>   
   </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>

Fixed data type for an element:
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="studentID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:attribute name="signedInteger" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="SignedInteger"/>
      </xs:complexType>   
   </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```